# Can't connect to paypal adaptive API for paykey - getting 400 bad request error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been researching and trying for 2 days to make a test call with PayPal Adaptive API
I hand wrote a fairly simple test code using php cURL...

```
        protected function makePayment($a=''){
            if($a==''){return 'OOPs';}

            $amount = "1.00";
            $receiver = "RECEIVER TEST EMAIL";

            $url = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/Pay';

            $paypalHeaders = array(
                'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID : XXXXXXXX',
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD : XXXXXXX',
            'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE : XXXXXXX',
        'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-VERSION: 1.8.6',
        'X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: <MY SITE IP>',
        'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT : NV',
        'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT : NV',
        'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID : APP-80W284485P519543T',
        'X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS: MY-SANDBOX-APP-OWNER@email.com'
                );

        //   Format the call payload.

            $payload = array(
                    "actionType"=>"PAY",
                    "currencyCode"=>"USD",
                    "receiverList"=>array(
                        "receiver"=>array(
                            array("amount"=>$amount,"email"=>$receiver)
                        )
                    ),
                    "returnUrl"=>"https://biddingblock.com/api/payment.php",
                    "cancelUrl"=>"https://biddingblock.com/index.htm",
                    "requestEnvelope"=>array(
                        "errorLanguage"=>"en_US",
                        "detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll"
                    )
                );  

            // Make the call

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $paypalHeaders);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Request);



            $Response = curl_exec($curl);       
            curl_close($curl);
            return $Response;
```

*** Every modification I have tried on this code still doesn't get past first base and I receive the following error back ***

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 176
Expires: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:31:45 GMT
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:31:45 GMT
Connection: close

An error occurred while processing your request.

Reference #166.d80300cc.1396269105.de2dda4

I am NOT using the Adaptive API PHP SDK and this is more or less the complete code minus the real keys and receiver email

What am I doing wrong?
Can someone please help?

PS: I have also tried this using DATA-FORMAT JSON   and JSON encoding the payload array.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$nvp = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE";
$nvp.= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19.95";              
$nvp.= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD";            
$nvp.= "&RETURNURL=http://www.dropial.com/success.html";  
$nvp.= "&CANCELURL=http://www.dropial.com/cancel.html";  

        $response = wpp_hash('SetExpressCheckout', $nvp);
        if ($response['ACK'] == 'Success') {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Payment Successful');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Payment Failed');
        }
```

The function wpp_hash is defined as:

```
public function wpp_hash($method = null, $nvp = null) {
        $curl_handler = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $required_nvp = 'METHOD='.$method;
        $required_nvp .= '&VERSION='.urlencode(Configure::read('Paypal.version'));
        $required_nvp .= '&USER='.urlencode(Configure::read('Paypal.username'));
        $required_nvp .= '&PWD='.urlencode(Configure::read('Paypal.password'));
        $required_nvp .= '&SIGNATURE='.urlencode(Configure::read('Paypal.signature'));

        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $required_nvp.$nvp);
        $http_responder = curl_exec($curl_handler);
        curl_close($curl_handler);

        pr($http_responder);
        if (!$http_responder) {
            throw new BadRequestException($method.'failed: '.curl_error($curl_handler).' ('.curl_errno($curl_handler).')');
        }

        $responder = explode('&', $http_responder);
        $parsed_response = array();

        foreach($responder as $response) {
            $response_array = explode('=', $response);
            if (count($response_array) >= 1){
                $parsed_response[$response_array[0]] = urldecode($response_array[1]);
            }
        }

        if ((count($parsed_response) < 1) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $parsed_response)){
            throw new BadRequestException('Invalid HTTP Response for POST request ('.$required_nvp.$nvp.') to '.Configure::read('Paypal.endpoint'));
        }

        return $parsed_response;
    }
```

You can change the method to use another PayPal transaction. In my case I'm using express checkout.

Comment: Using the correct endpoint is important: HTTPS:// api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

Comment: I notice for your code that it appears you are using the PHP Adaptive SDK?

I am not using the SQK as illustrated in my original POS, it is possible to connect to the sandbox without using the SDK?

My problem seems to occur because I am not successfully connecting to the sandbox at all, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I could not however get this wot work on my server.

Comment: Sorry by my delay. I'm not using PHP Adaptive SDK, just cURL.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved beyond this and used a work around by running this with the following method.

Thanks

Here is the solution I have adopted...

```
        $payload = array(
            "actionType"=>"PAY",
            "currencyCode"=>"USD",
            "receiverList"=>array(
                "receiver"=>array(
                    array("amount"=>$amount,"email"=>$receiver)
                )
            ),
            "feesPayer"=>"PRIMARYRECEIVER",
            "returnUrl"=>"MyRETURN_URL",
            "cancelUrl"=>"MyCANCEL_URL",
            "requestEnvelope"=>array(
                "errorLanguage"=>"en_US",
                "detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll"
            )
        );  

 $request = 'curl -s --insecure'.$TEST_url.' -d "'.addslashes(json_encode($payload)).'"';

 $response = json_decode(exec($request));
```